# Is it safe to remove <NextScript /> from the `_document.js`?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is the custom `_document.js`

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

According to the [Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-document)  `<Html>`, `<Head />`, `<Main />` and `<NextScript />` are required for page to be properly rendered.

I have removed `<NextScript />` for the testing purpose and it works fine. Does someone point what issue occurs if I remove this completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing `NextScript` you would be removing any JavaScript that is required to run on the client side. Instead all your page will contain is the server rendered HTML and CSS

Basically a page that appears when the user switches off the JavaScript in the browser. If you are okay with that being the case, then you can go along with removing it.

But just removing it wouldn't help with the network load, you would have to create a custom `Head` to remove the preload scripts.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4634)

Comment: The main target is to remove the `__NEXT_DATA__ ` from the HTML. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: That is very required for the hydration process on the client

Answer (score 0):

This is the `NextScript` class according to the documentation!

```
export class NextScript extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    _documentProps: PropTypes.any
  }

  static propTypes = {
    nonce: PropTypes.string
  }

  getDynamicChunks () {
    const { dynamicImports, assetPrefix } = this.context._documentProps
    return dynamicImports.map((bundle) => {
      return <script
        async
        key={bundle.file}
        src={`${assetPrefix}/_next/${bundle.file}`}
            nonce={this.props.nonce}
      />
    })
  }
```

and according to [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/8980) pull request NextScript uses the async attribute to load javascript. The async attribute allows javascript parsing and execution to interrupt the main thread which could be in the middle of parsing the DOM. Interrupting the DOM will increase the time to first contentful paint.

Comment: So it is safe to remove, but not advised for performance reasons?

Comment: It seems nothing really happens.And maybe in the future it will be removed by nextjs community and replaced with something trivial inside next core!

Take a look at this : https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4634